# Trying to copy two cells from multiple workbooks into a single worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy two cells `B2 & C2` from  the `Results` worksheet on every single workbook within a folder and then paste cells in a Master workbook starting in cell `A1, A2, A3 etc`

I found a tutorial that almost does what I'm looking for, I've attempted to edit it.

I'm not sure how to have the data appear on the same worksheet within the master as this I think will add a new sheet per workbook in the folder.

The last line here: `ActiveWorkbook.Close Save = False`

Is giving me the error: `Expected Function or Variable.` with `Save` being highlighted as the issue.

```
 'Copy cells B2 & C2 from the results worksheet
Worksheets("Results").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(3, 2)).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close Save = False
```

Full Code.

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim WorkbookCounter As Long
WorkbookCounter = 1
Dim Filepath As String

Filepath = "C:\Test\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)

'Copy cells B2 & C2 from the results worksheet
Worksheets("Results").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(3, 2)).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close Save = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Paste cells B2 & C2 to A1
Sheets(WorkbookCounter).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(WorkbookCounter).Range("A1")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1
If WorkbookCounter > 1000 Then
Exit Sub
End If

MyFile = Dir
Loop
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `ActiveSheet.Range("B2:C2").Copy` instead.

Comment: Or `Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, 3)).Copy`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Same error with ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(q).Range(“A1”) now. Anyone know what this error means?

Comment: Check the type of `“ ”` marks you are using, the ones in your comment and the code in the question for that line don't look like the standard `" "` type.

Comment: @DavidP good spot, adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using letters for columns when you need to be using numbers. You have:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(B, 2), Cells(C, 2)).Copy
```

But `B` and `C` are not variables and the `Cells` function is looking for a column index there. Replace B and C with 2 and 3 respectively.